# Verbs that require either an accusative or genitive object, depending on their nature

Tags: глаголы, родительный-падеж, винительный-падеж

Apparently, there is a number of verbs that may require either an accusative or genitive object, depending on their nature.

1. If it's a specific, concrete object, the accusative would apply: I wait for the bus = Я жду автобус (accusative masculine inanimate, as I'm waiting for a specific bus);
2. I wait for peace = Я жду мира (genitive masculine, as it is more conceptual, less defined).
   Other verbs with the same behaviour include:

- бояться (to fear, to be afraid of – for this verb, we would only use the accusative when we are afraid of a given person);
- добиваться (to reach);
- достигать (to achieve);
- ждать (to wait);
- желать (rather in the sense of “to desire”, than “to wish”);
- искать (to look for);
- ожидать (to expect);
- просить (to ask, to request);
- требовать (to demand);
- хотеть (to want).

My question is twofold:

a)  Am I forgetting some other verbs with the same behaviour or is the above list exhaustive?

b)  Would this rule also apply to the imperfective/perfective pair of each of the above verbs?

What about, for example, the following pairs:

- спрашивать/спросить (to ask, to inquire);
- требоваться/потребоваться (to be required);
- хотеться/захотеться (to feel like).

Would they also follow the same pattern?

Comment: Thank you @CocoPop for the corrections.

Comment: You're very welcome, Xavier. Very little to correct))

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe add "понимать" = to understand.

**Я не понимаю вопрос.** (I don't understand the question) — accusative

You could also say:

**Я не понимаю вопроса.** It would mean the same thing as "Я не понимаю, в чём состоит вопрос" (I don't understand what the question is. To me, it's all very obvious) — genitive

Same as in:

**Я не понимаю проблемы.** (I don't see a problem here) — genitive

The same goes for "видеть" = to see

When you use the accusative, it literally means "to see" (when something is visible, and you're able to see with your eyes)

**Я вижу кота. / Я не вижу кота.** (I see a cat / I don't see a cat) — accusative

When you use the genitive (usually with negation), it takes on a more figurative meaning, like you don't see something (a problem, an issue) because in your opinion, it doesn't exist.

**Я не вижу проблемы.** (I don't see a problem = there's no problem) — genitive